# Spring 3.0 MVC , Unable to register Home Controller , 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have configured hibernate & Spring without any errors and my project is deploying, however I’m try to load my Home.jsp via a controller “HomeController” but I’m getting “Error :404 Resource not found…”:

---

I have tried 3 different approaches:

**Approach Number 1 (Not my ideal approach).**

a)  Define a index.htm in welcome list (web.xml)

b)  Map HomeController to “/index.htm” via annotations using @Controller @RequestMethod

c)  HomeController returns view “Home” (WEB-INF/views/Home.jsp)

---

Common project structure used for all 3 approaches:

[image]

---

**Web.xml:**

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout> 
            30 
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Yourmarketnet-spring.xml snippet:**

```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"     
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes --> 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.   For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />    
    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.  Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- mapping of static resources-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

**HomeController Class:**

```
package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/index.htm") 
public class HomeController {  
    public String requestHandler()
    { 
        return "Home"; 
    } 
}
```

**Result of Running application :**

Http Status 404

The requested resource () is not available.

---

**Approach Number 2,  (Not my ideal approach)**

a)  Create redirect.jsp , and define welcome list (web.xml)

b)  Map HomeController to “ /HomeController” via annotations  using @Controller @RequestMethod

c)  Have redirect.jsp “<% response.sendRedirect("/HomeController");%>” to my HomeController

d)  HomeController returns view “Home” (WEB-INF/views/Home.jsp)

**Web.xml:**

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout> 
            30 
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Yourmarketnet-spring.xml snippet:**

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"     
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
 </beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml snippet:**

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes --> 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.   For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />    
    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.  Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- mapping of static resources-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

**HomeController Class:**

```
package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/HomeController") 
public class HomeController {  
    public String requestHandler()
    { 
        return "Home"; 
    } 
}
```

**Result of Running application :**

Http Status 404 /HomeController

The requested resource (/HomeController) is not available.

---

**Approach Number 3,  (If any off the above works its fine, however this is what I really want)**

a)  Remove all welcome file tags from web.xml

b)  MapDispatcher to “/”

c)  Map HomeController to  “/HomeController” via annotations using @Controller @RequestMethod'

d)  HomeController returns view “Home” (WEB-INF/views/Home.jsp)

**Web.xml:**

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout> 
            30 
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Yourmarketnet-spring.xml snippet: **

```
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"     
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
```

**applicationContext.xml snippet:**

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes --> 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.   For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />    
    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.  Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- mapping of static resources-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

**HomeController Class:**

```
package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class HomeController {

    public String requestHandler()
    { 
        return "Home"; 
    } 
}
```

**Apache Server log:**

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/yourmarketnet/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'yourmarketnet'

**Result of Running application :**

Http Status 404

The requested resource () is not available.

Please provide me with the correct code/tags in order to server my Home.jsp from HomeController without 404 Error, Thank you.

Comment: Annotate controller method too, in addition (or without) to @RequestMapping annotation at class level

Comment: Ravi your are absolutely write I added the @RequestMapping(value="/" , method=RequestMethod.GET) to my method and eveything worked , Thanks a million buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am talking about the third approach from your question.

In your web.xml change the request mapping to `/` instead of `*.htm`.
Everything else if just perfect as I can see here. So this should work for you.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: That was just a typo in my posting , in the actual project its "/". Thanks